# Prevent repeated keystrokes from VNC (Windows)

Tags: python, keyboard, windows, vnc

I'm trying to capture keyup and keydown events on Raspian, using VNC from Windows.  I would expect the code below to acknowledge only when I first press the key and again when I release it; however, when I press a key, it repeatedly reports "1 down" "1 up" etc.  The code below works with a local keyboard.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
width, height = 200, 200
pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
start_key = pygame.K_1-1
key_state_dict = {}
key_state_dict = {i:-1 for i in range(1,9)}

#pygame.key.set_repeat(0)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit(); #sys.exit() if sys is imported
        for i in range (1, 9):
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == i+start_key:
                    print str(i)+" down"
                    key_state_dict[i] = 1
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == i+start_key:
                   print str(i)+" up"
                   key_state_dict[i] = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation I saw seems to suggest that the keyboard repeat rate is initially set to disabled (presumably the setting equals 0 {milliseconds})

From pygame 1.8 it says you can use `pygame.key.get_repeat()` - what does that indicate?

`pygame.key.set_repeat(`*n*`)` - where n is repeat interval in milliseconds - configures the setting; it might be worth using anyhow, even *with* the default supposedly being what you would want.